# Swift saving multiple images to the filesystem at once, High CPU

Tags: swift, recursion, memory, uiimage, realm

I have the following func, I need to clear out all picture columns in a DB and move to the file system. When I did this all in one go, there was too much memory and it would crash. I switched to a recursive function and do the writes and batches of 20.

There are about 6 tables which I need to do this for. There is 2 and half gigs of data in my Realm DB. This gets switched to 40mb after I call my 6 recursive functions, taking images out and compressing Realm.

I can see very high memory usage as my functions are called and phones with less RAM would not be able to handle it.

How can I free up memory and CPU in between each function?

```
public static func clearEqCatPics(){

        let docsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let eqcatPicDir = docsDir.appendingPathComponent(util_Constants.DIR_EQCAT_PICS)

        do {
            var realm : Realm? = try Realm()
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "icon != %@", "")
            let categories = realm!.objects(STD_EQ_category.self).filter(predicate).sorted( by: [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "displayorder", ascending: true), SortDescriptor(keyPath: "_id", ascending: true)] )

            if (categories.count > 0)
            {
                realm?.beginWrite()
                let upper = categories.count > 20 ? 20 : categories.count

                var actualCounter = upper
                for i in 0..<upper{
                    autoreleasepool{
                        if let proPicData = Data(base64Encoded: categories[actualCounter - 1].icon, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {


                            let filename = eqcatPicDir.appendingPathComponent(categories[actualCounter - 1]._id.description+".jpg")

                            (proPicData as NSData).writeToURL2(named: filename, completion: { (result, url) -> Void in

                            })

                            categories[actualCounter - 1].icon = ""

                        }
                        else{
                            categories[actualCounter - 1].icon = ""
                        }
                    }

                    actualCounter = actualCounter - 1

                }

                try realm?.commitWrite()
                let eqcatNew = realm!.objects(STD_EQ_category.self).filter(predicate)
                print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 2. eqcatNew COUNT : \(eqcatNew.count) $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
                realm = nil
                if eqcatNew.count > 0 {
                    clearEqCatPics()
                }
            }
            realm = nil
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("error realm \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }

    }
```

where writeToURL2 IS:

I needed to get rid of the weak self in my extension because I was getting past the guard let for multiple items and loads were being skipped

```
extension NSData {

    func writeToURL2(named:URL, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ url:NSURL?) -> Void)  {


        let tmpURL = named as NSURL

        //[weak self]
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {  () -> Void in

            //guard let strongSelf = self else { print("self was weak"); completion (false, tmpURL); return }

            self.write(to: tmpURL as URL, atomically: true)
            var error:NSError?
            if tmpURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
                print("We have it")
                completion(true, tmpURL)
            } else {
                print("We Don't have it\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completion (false, tmpURL)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I changed my writeToURL in my for loop to the following:

```
do {
     try proPicData.write(to: filename, options: [.atomic])                               
}
catch let err as NSError{
     print("err : \(err.localizedDescription)")
}
```

It helped with memory, But sometimes I get Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointing to the line try proPicData.write...

Still have very high CPU usage. Is there anyway to clear out CPU usage in between each function call?

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching all of the objects in your `Realm` at the same time, that is what is using up so much memory

`let categories = realm!.objects(STD_EQ_category.self).filter(predicate).sorted( by: [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "displayorder", ascending: true), SortDescriptor(keyPath: "_id", ascending: true)] )`

The writing to files is not what is using up memory, although that might have something to do with the CPU usage.

I would recommend putting a `limit` on the categories fetch so that you don't load all categories and their images into memory. Otherwise, try to come up with a fetch predicate that would otherwise limit the data in a sensible way.

Comment: only as I go through and access the realm objects in my for loop are they loading into memory. As they are lazily loaded. I changed the write to url, now instead of putting it off to a background thread, I just directly call the normal data.write(to url, option: [.atomic], in my for loop. Now memory gets up to 50 or 60mb but CPU goes up too high causing the crash

Comment: Have you tried using instruments to see exactly where the problem is? Otherwise, maybe there is a problem with the `realm.commitWrite()` doing too much work at once trying to free up the images?

Comment: when profiling in instruments, where exactly do I look to see this?

Comment: I have had the best luck with the Time Profiler - try using that. You might have to fiddle with it a bit (and maybe your code) to get quality output. There are other utilities you could try as well, pretty much pick one from the list that sounds like it does something that could help you.